# attributerouting limitations in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

In the documentation for attributerouting, there are a series of warnings that says that "[performance enhancements when matching routes](http://attributerouting.net/#asp-net-web-api)" does not work.  What kind of performance enhancements are they talking about, and what does that mean in terms of performance in a production based system - is it significant enough to not not consider attributerouting on a production system?

What about a bit more details about custom route handlers and query string parameter constraints?  What do they mean by "custom" and as for the querystring constraints, is that constraints on data type?

I'd like to understand this a bit more and also measure it's impact in my use-cases to judge whether the attribute routing package for web-api is suitable for my production api.

Answer (score 4):

**SUMMARY**

Make your evaluation based on [the ASP.NET v5 RTM Beta](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/releases/view/101957), either from [source](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) or [nightly build](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds), since **it includes AttributeRouting**.

**DETAIL**

*Merger*

AttributeRouting has been absorbed into ASP.NET v5 RTM with AR's package owner Tim McCall's cooperation. v5 has bee in beta since February 2013. Please see [ASP.NET Roadmap](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap) on [the ASP.NET Documentation site](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/documentation).

*Custom Route Handlers*

*Parameter Constraints*

The HttpVerbAttribute-based classes support (examples from [AttributeRoutingTest.cs](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/System.Web.Http.Test/Routing/AttributeRoutingTest.cs)):

Parameter type constraints

```
    [HttpGet("controller/{id:int}")]
    public string Get(int id) { ... }
```

Optional parameters

```
    [HttpGet("optional/{opt1?}/{opt2?}")]
    public string Optional(string opt1 = null, string opt2 = null) { ... }
```

In-attribute defaults

```
    [HttpGet("default/{default1=D1}/{default2=D2}")]
    public string Default(string default1, string default2) { ... }
```

Wildcard parameters

```
    [HttpGet("wildcard/{*wildcard}")]
    public string Wildcard(string wildcard) { ... }
```

Comment: I looked in that documentation and was referring to it in the question, specifically the sentences outlined...

Comment: I have added to my answer, but please note, I was and am not referring you to the AttributeRouting site. I refer you to the ASP.NET Roadmap site, where it is explained that AttributeRouting is part of ASP.NET now.  AttributeRouting owner Tim McCall was trying to get the ASP.NET team to change certain items in the Web API part from internal to public. His collaboration with the ASP.NET to merge AR in would have given him the change to address the outlined items.  I will add a comment or extend my answer once I find detail in the code that the performance gains he wanted were accomplished.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused, the roadmap page just has a paragraph blurb about it and links to the attribute routing project.  Anyways, does that mean all routing in attribute routing has a performance problem?  Is it significantly slower than asp.net mvc, and if so are there any benchmarks?  The listed "performance enhancements when matching routes" just sounds very vague.  I'm trying to gauge just how much of a "problem" that is or if it's just merely an incremental enhancement.

Comment: My understanding is that Web API cannot be enhanced and MVC already has been.  When I find the code, I will update here...

Comment: Any further word on this Pete? I'm very excited about the idea of ASP.NET v5.0 containing AR - that's fantastic. I'm curious, too, about what you mean by "WebAPI cannot be enhanced"? There's already an AR solution for WebAPI that we've used - is it not getting picked up for inclusion, but the MVC version is?

Comment: @Troy, I have not gotten back to digging for this answer yet.  By "Web API", I meant "Attribute Routing for Web API".  Enhancements would be done either in ASP.NET Web API 2.0, or ASP.NET Web API vNext.